# UISegmentedControl selected indexvalue to post to webservice

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, uisegmentedcontrol, xcode5.1

I have a UISegmentedControl like array. I should pass the selected index value (like 0, 1 or 2..) to NSMutableDictionary. Now I have to post the selected index value to webservice.

Comment: Okay, that sounds interesting. Do you have any question? A problem? Probably some code to show us?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the string value of selected segmented control from following lines of code.

```
// I think you have UISegmentedControl like this. 
UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Text1",@"Text2",@"Text3", nil]];

// Bellow line convert the integer value of selected segment to NSString
NSString *strSelectedSegmented = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex];

// Bellow line print the string value of selected segment.
NSLog(@"String value of selected UISegmentedControl: %@",strSelectedSegmented);
```

Now, you have strSelectedSegmented which have string value of Selected Segment. You can use the string value to post in web-service.

Comment: If you need the title of selected segment. try following line of code. 

NSLog(@"selected segment title: %@",[segmentedControl titleForSegmentAtIndex:segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex]);

Answer (score 0):

To check selected segment for UISegmentedControl, use following line:

```
objectOfUISegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex;
```

But, this line must placed in a method which is handling  UISegmentedControl.

put the following code to create UISegmentedControl.

```
[objSegment addTarget:self action:@selector(handleSegmentControl:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

put first code snippet statement in handleSegmentControl method.

If you have any query, Contact me.